# SSRS SSL through a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, reporting-services, load-balancing

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services instance running in amazon, and I want to access it from outside of our network over SSL.  To do that, I've setup a load balancer which will forward the requests on 443 to the server.

This is working fine, and when I load the URL for the report server it gives me the windows login prompt for my domain credentials.  The issue seems to be when I give it my credentials, it doesn't accept them, or doesn't seem to store the auth token properly, as it repeatedly asks for my credentials.

Anyone have experience routing requests for SSRS through a load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue - changed the ELB to transfer TCP (or SSL) to TCP instead of HTTP (or HTTPS). Solved the issue.